# Ubuntu 16.04 DisplayPort 1.2 MST not working with Radeon driver

Tags: 16.04, drivers, multiple-monitors, radeon

I am trying to use 6 monitors using 2 DP1.2 MST hubs with Ubuntu 16.04.

When I plug everything in, Ubuntu only recognizes 2 monitors, and the 3 monitors across each hub just get mirrored.

[image]

I am using:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- 6x [HP VH240a monitors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B072M34RQC)
- 2x [Startech MSTMDP123HD](https://www.startech.com/AV/Displayport-Converters/Mini-DisplayPort-Triple-Head-HDMI-Multi-Monitor-MST-Hub~MSTMDP123HD) MST hubs
- Radeon HD 6950 GPU with the Radeon driver

Here is the `xrandr` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 inverted (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-1 connected 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Does the Radeon driver just not support DisplayPort1.2 MST? I really don't want to have to buy another GPU just so that I can use the AMDGPU driver.

Any advice on how I can get this setup to work would be much appreciated.

Update: I booted into my old 14.04 partition and switched to the `fglrx` driver. MST works with `fglrx`. Now I just have to figure out how to get 16.04 to work.